# How to scroll automatically to a specific item in a wrappanel?

Tags: c#, scroll, wrappanel

Currently i collaborate in a big software project and i got a problem with a nice feature i trying to implement.

The problem is, i dont know how to scroll automatically to a specific item which is able to be selected by some user. The wrappanel is used as an itemspaneltemplate from an itemscontrol.

The code follows for a better understanding:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding SomeData}">
   <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
      <ItemsPanelTemplate>
         <WrapPanel />
      </ItemsPanelTemplate>
   </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
   <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <SomeChart DataContext="{Binding }" Focusable="True" />
      </DataTemplate>
   </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Sorry for my bad explanation my problem is not that i cant set the focus. My problem is to scroll automatically to the selected item so that will be displayed. The list is longer then the display and at the moment you must scroll manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mentioned an `ItemsControl`, most of the controls that derive from an ItemsControl have a **[ScrollIntoView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.scrollintoview.aspx)** method to scroll the Listbox/Datagrid to the currently selected item.

For example:

```
listBox1.ScrollIntoView(listBox1.SelectedIndex);
```

or

```
dataGrid1.ScrollIntoView(dataGrid1.SelectedIndex);
```

Here's another solution for a [ListView](http://dotnet-experience.blogspot.com.es/2010/12/wpf-listview-scrollintoview.html).

**Update:**
Listbox with Wrappanel

```
<ListBox x:Name="myList">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel ItemHeight="150" ItemWidth="150"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
</Listbox>
```

Comment: Yes something like the scrollintoview method is exactly what i need but a wrappanel hasnt such a method. Which alternatives for a wrappanel can i use?? in the itemscontrol??

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do, but why not put a wrappanel in a ListBox instead of an ItemsControl? Added example to my answer

Comment: Ah sorry its my fault. I didnt know that the listbox is an alternative for the itemscontrol. Thanks for your help its exactly what i need.